# How do you get the largest integer from a maximum methods in JAVA?

Tags: java, integer, max

Hi I am doing a beginners course on JAVA and I do not know exactly how to solve this challenge. Here is the question and the info provide it:
Write a method  that returns the largest integer in the list. You can assume that the list has at least one element.

```
public Integer maximum(Integer[] numList) { 
 // enter your code here 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Vincente, welcome to SO. Take a look at this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: the cool thing about programming is you never know *exactly* how to solve a challenge, but you start with something and then gradually improve it until something workable is achieved. You haven't even started, so we have no idea how to help you...

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. Once you've tried some code that you're willing to post here, we'll be glad to help you with specific problems.

Comment: `java.util.stream.IntStream.of(numArray).max().getAsInt()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Collection.max()`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    System.out.println(Collections.max(numList));
  }
}
```

**Output**

`4`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're interested in actually learning **how to do this**, rather than just *getting it done*, here's the basic method:

1. Start by guessing that the first number on the list, `numList[0]` is the largest; remember that guess.
2. Look at the rest of the numbers in `numList` one by one; for each one,
   test whether or not it's larger than your current guess of the largest number and if it is, make that number your new guess.
3. When you've looked at all the numbers in `numList`, your most recent guess will be the actual largest number in the entire list.